# Ember - Return a promise from beforeModel not working with Qunit

Tags: ember.js, qunit

In my `ApplicationRoute` I implement a `beforeModel` hook that does a server call to see if a valid session exists. If it does, then the app navigates to the 'dashboard' route, otherwise it goes to the 'login' route. I am trying to implement some tests and I can't seem to get it to work with QUnit. I keep getting:

> Assertion failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the
>   run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous
>   side-effects in an Ember.run

Here is a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/e0Q4qz?p=preview I have simulated a server call by creating a `doLater` method that returns a promise and executes a method in a few milliseconds. The only way I can get it to work is to not return a promise from the `beforeModel` hook. Am I using `App.deferReadiness()` and `Ember.run()` correctly?

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('dashboard');
  this.resource('login');
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  alreadyChecked: false,

  beforeModel: function() {
    var route = this;

    // uncomment this line to stop this hook returning a promise
    // return route.transitionTo(localStorage.user ? 'dashboard' : 'login');

    if (!this.alreadyChecked) {
      return doLater(function() {
        // without the alreadyChecked flag, this function gets called twice
        route.set('alreadyChecked', false);
        route.transitionTo(localStorage.user ? 'dashboard' : 'login');
      });
    }
  }
});

App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    login: function() {
      var route = this;
      doLater(function() {
        localStorage.user = "Bill";
        route.transitionTo('dashboard');
      });
    }
  }
});

App.DashboardRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    logout: function() {
      var route = this;
      doLater(function() {
        localStorage.user = "";
        route.transitionTo('login');
      });
    }
  }
});

function doLater(fn) {
  return Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(fn());
    }, 500);
  });
}


// run the tests
if (true) { // toggle this boolean to run the app in testing mode
  App.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
  App.setupForTesting();
  App.injectTestHelpers();

  module('integration tests', {
    setup: function() {
      Ember.run(function() {
        App.reset();
        localStorage.user = "";
        App.deferReadiness();
      });
    }
  });

  test('can navigate to login page', function() {
    expect(1);
    Ember.run(App, 'advanceReadiness');
    visit("/login").then(function() {
      ok(true, "Tests work");
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, adding the example is awesome, shows you tried, and makes it so much easier to debug.

In your case there is no need to advance readiness, and the problem is setTimeout lives outside of the run loop, but Ember.run.later doesn't and works the same!

http://plnkr.co/edit/lZKM4JBluQ27rcnfXlWS?p=preview

http://plnkr.co/edit/wFOCGQt3ahiuqi8el0rB?p=preview

Comment: Cool, I think that's getting closer, but I want to be able to replace the `setTimeout` with a `Ember.$.ajax` call. Do I have to wrap all my server calls? Editing the `doLater` function to perform a server now breaks.

`function doLater(fn) {
  Ember.$.ajax("blah").always(function() {
    resolve(fn());
  });
}`

Comment: Sorry, not having much luck - where should the the `Ember.run` go? http://plnkr.co/edit/OydChL?p=preview I don't seem to be able to put it anywhere that doesn't break the passing of the results back up through the promise.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go but it seems a bit lame that I have to put `Ember.run`'s all over the place and not just in my tests.

Comment: The problem is you're modifying the page outside of the scope of a single event, so Ember has no way of knowing you'll be doing that without leaving the run loop on, which would mess up testing/performance.

Comment: After getting used to it, the run loop and unit testing is awesome, it's so easy to manipulate the page and know when everything is done (the run loop is empty, properties have propagated, things have updated everywhere etc)