# Ember RSVP Promise for model not resolving with firefox addon port messaging scheme

Tags: javascript, ember.js, firefox-addon-sdk

Below is the code example. This is for addon panel.

The router promise does not get resolved from inside global listner, though it works with normal ajax requests.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({


  model: function() {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

// This works 
Ember.$.ajax({
    url : "http://bla.com"
    type: "POST"
    }).then(function(response){
        resolve(response);;
    });


// This doesn't work
addon.port.on(url, function(status, response) {
    resolve(response); 
})



  });
});
```

I read somewhere this can be handled with Ember.run.bind but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Does it work with asynchronous functions that are not from Ember (e.g. native XHR or `setTimeout)`?

Comment: Probably not.
from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602692/ember-return-a-promise-from-beforemodel-not-working-with-qunit and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685055/rsvp-handling-timeouts-with-promises

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you `Ember.run.join(this, resolve, response)` ?

```
addon.port.on(url, function(status, response) {
    // just in case it doesn't work, add a log here to make sure your callback
    // is actually being called.
    console.log('got response');
    Ember.run.join(this, resolve, response); 
});
```

[`Ember.run.join`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_join) will join an existing run loop or create a new one.

Comment: It give me this error Message: TypeError: this.get(...).toArray is not a function.

"response" is an array [] in callback.

Comment: It looks like the promise is not waiting for getting fulfilled, and thus the model is not properly formed. Is there a way we can tell ember to wait for message on addon.port.on() ?